# My upper_bound function does not work with class string attribute

Tags: c++, search, vector, lower-bound, upperbound

I have a vector filled with client class objects sorted by name. The problem starts when I try to get the "highest" name(string class) searched.

A brief example of my problem:

```
int main()
{
  vector<Client> vCli;
  vector<Client>::iterator low;
  vector<Client>::iterator up;

  myClass c1(1, "John Lil", 123);
  myClass c2(2, "John Bob", 325);
  myClass c3(3, "Alves Hunk", 472);
  myClass c4(4, "Gil Diniz", 521);
  myClass c5(5, "Boll Yo", 181);

  c_Cli.push_back(c1);
  c_Cli.push_back(c2);
  c_Cli.push_back(c3);
  c_Cli.push_back(c4);
  c_Cli.push_back(c5);

  sort(vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), auxPesqNome[](Cliente a, Cliente b) {return a.name < b.name;} );
  /* Correct sort = Alves Hunk, Boll Yo, Gil Diniz,John Bob ,John Lil  */


  low = lower_bound (vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), "John", [](Cliente a, Cliente b) {return a.name < b.name;});
  up  = upper_bound (vCli.begin(), vCli.end(), "John", [](Cliente a, Cliente b) {return a.name < b.name;});

  cout << (low - vCli.begin()) << endl; 
  /* Correct output  = 3 */

  cout << (up - vCli.begin()) << endl;
  /* ***INCORRECT output  = 3 *** */


  return 0
}
```

I think the problem may be in compound names, but my little experience in c ++ can't solve it.

I would like to replace "lower_bound" and "upper_bound" with "equal_range".

Comment: Please make sure examples you provide can be compiled. By the time I'm done patching up all of the compiler errors in this code I'll probably have accidentally fixed the error you're looking for. Use [mcve] as inspiration.

Comment: `John Bob` is *greater* than `John`. `upper_bound` returns the iterator to the first element that is greater than `John`, which is `vCli.begin() + 3`.

Comment: what is "the problem" what output did you expect and why?

Comment: Unrelated: if you compile to one of the modern standards (C++11 or newer) you can use [List Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to save yourself a bunch of effort setting up the `vector`. Eg: `vector<Client> vCli{{1, "John Lil", 123}, {2, "John Bob", 325}, ...};` All of the `cN` variables and the `push_back`s are no longer needed.

Comment: @user4581301  I'm studying it yet. Thank you